# Why are edits for new tag entries getting rejected for changing too much of the original content?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I have been trying to edit/add tag wiki information. Most of my suggested edits are getting approved, but I do notice with the ones rejected (and some reject votes on the accepted ones), they have listed the reason as:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning
>   or intent of the post would be lost.

You can look at my first few tag wiki edits to see this. These were all for tags that did not have any content prior to me suggesting the edits, so I am confused as to what the reasoning behind this is.

I am sure this has been addressed somewhere, but did not find anything searching Meta on here or on a couple other sites. I was just wondering if someone could clear this up for me so I can be more productive in my editing, and not waste reviewers time if my edits are not right.

Comment: That's...strange. Maybe the person didn't realize they were tag wiki edits? If you were creating the wiki that seems hard to miss though

Comment: Which tags were they if you can remember them?

Comment: @slm - the tag wikis for Asterisk, chkconfig, and Chef are examples. The tag wiki excerpts for dnsmasq and chkconfig are other examples. Like I stated, most of my suggested edits are getting accepted - I just want to make sure my edits are not borderline bad or something like that (and understand the real reason some are getting rejected, so I can improve them).

Comment: When I started reviewing I noticed the tags coming through and then realized that reviewers review these in addition to suggested edits. Initially that caught me off guard and after digging I realized that reviewing entailed edits to the posts as well as to the tags. I could see how someone new to reviewing could get confused and might dismiss the tag edits as "too minor" if they didn't understand that aspect to the site.

Comment: @slm - An edit being "too minor" is not the subject of this post - The reviewers are marking tag wiki edits as "This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost." That being said, if an editor doesn't take full dedication in understanding what is needed/required to make a proper review, maybe said editor should be stripped of their reviewing privileges. As obviously they do not understand what they are doing, so they really have no purpose doing it.

Comment: @BriGuy - "too minor" or "too much" are being driven by the choices provided you when reviewing. Like I said, the tag reviews are thrown in with the reviews for edits to answers so I can see how a reviewer might think a tag edit is "too much", esp. if they aren't familiar with tags across the SE sites.

Comment: @BriGuy - I see it slightly differently wrt being a reviewer. Reviewing is a skill that ppl have to acquire over time. Obviously ppl have to put time in to get good at it, but it's a slightly different skill then answering questions. I've found the documentation very lacking wrt how to be a good reviewer across all the SE sites. The info -is- out there but it's completely fragmented and disorganized. Just my $0.02.